# Can someone provide online resources to learn Vipassana and Metta?

Tags: vipassana, reference-request, meditation-metta

Anything like a PDF or a website link or a podcast audio is OK for me :)

Answer (score 5):

Here I am listing some useful resources for an introduction to Vipassana as taught by S. N. Goenka in the tradition of Sayagyi U Ba Khin:

1. [An Introduction to Vipassana](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HbfHERChbmw)
2. [S. N. Goenka's Inspiring Speech at United Nations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xy9PugTy15M)
3. [Eilona Ariel's (A documentary filmmaker and Vipassana meditator) TedX Talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ixu4Kd5R1DI)
4. [Doing Time, Doing Vipassana - a documentary on use of Vipassana in Tihar Jail](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WkxSyv5R1sg)
5. [Dhamma.org - link for 10 day course registration at one of many centres in the world](http://www.dhamma.org/en-US/index)
6. [Introduction to the technique of Vipassana and Code of Discipline for the meditation courses](http://www.dhamma.org/en/docs/core/code-en.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

Here are some links......

http://mahamevnawa.com/Amadahara_FrnDw/Mp3_JeewanandaThero/28_Meththaa.MP3

http://mahamevnawa.com/Amadahara_FrnDw/Mp3_JeewanandaThero/49_Asuba_Aanaapaana_sathi.mp3

http://mahamevnawa.com/Amadahara_FrnDw/Mp3_JeewanandaThero/75_Anapanasathi_Bhavana.mp3

http://mahamevnawa.com/Amadahara_FrnDw/Mp3_JeewanandaThero/77_Meditation_of_Foulness.mp3

http://mahamevnawa.com/Amadahara_FrnDw/Mp3_JeewanandaThero/79_Meditation_on_Nine_Cemetery_Contemplations.mp3

Comment: Please identify which specific posts/links within your blog are an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/9125/254) has details and references to resources on the Mahasi Sayadaw method of vipassanā.

Answer (score 1):

I also recommend Allan Wallace's podcasts, he has 40 years of experience and is a very good meditation teacher.

For example this course, [Fall 2012 Shamatha, Vipashyana and the Four Applications of Mindfulness](http://media.sbinstitute.com/courses/fall2012/), is on vipassana.

Also, check out his books. He has written many, so I won't be specific. But try browsing him by subject and see what you like.

For me personally I've gotten a lot of direct help from people on this forum too. There are many very experienced,  helpful and competent guys here.

Comment: Do you know, which of the podcasts on the page you linked to are resources for Metta and/or Vipasanna meditation?

Comment: I can ask the guy who gave me the link, I'm meeting him tomorrow.

Comment: Hi ChrisW, I think  this one from fall 2012 is on vipassana, http://media.sbinstitute.com/courses/fall2012/

Comment: Thank you (I edited the answer because for answers to a [tag:reference-request] it's probably more helpful to give a specific reference to the thing requested -- instead of a link to a web site which might contain the thing requested somewhere, leaving the OP still to search for it).

Answer (score 1):

The [Wildmind](http://www.wildmind.org/) website provides instructions on several types of meditation practiced in the Triratna Buddhist Community. The techniques include, among others, the [lovingkindness meditation (mettā bhāvāna)](http://www.wildmind.org/metta).

Answer (score 1):

Ven. Yuttadhammo has a book : http://static.sirimangalo.org/howto/HTM.pdf

Comment: This book describes (a form of) Vipassana, doesn't it.

Comment: it does :) should i edit my answer to reflect that ?